# differentiability of bizarre piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $T = \{3k \mid k \in \Bbb Z \}$ and $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll}
x^2, && x \in T \\
x, && x \notin T \end{array} \right.$.

Show that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Attempt at the question: Let $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)} {x-0} = \frac{f(x)} x$; we prove that $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)} x$ exists.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Now I don't know what $\delta$ to use. Or maybe this is not the way to approach this question?

Comment: Why don't you try $\delta = \min\{\varepsilon, 1\}$?

Answer (score 0):

In the range $(-3,3)$, $f(x)$ strictly coincides with $x$, as $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ elsewhere. The derivative at $x=0$ is $1$.

---

By the way, the derivative is $1$ everywhere, except in $T\setminus\{0\}$, because $f(3k)=9k^2\ne3k$.